# Storing AES Secret key using keystore in java

Tags: java, encryption, aes, keystore

I am using Java keystore to store the secret key for AES encryption.

```
final String strToEncrypt = "Hello World";
KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
kg.init(128);
SecretKey sk = kg.generateKey();
String secretKey = String.valueOf(Hex.encodeHex(sk.getEncoded()));   
//Storing AES Secret key in keystore
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
char[] password = "keystorepassword".toCharArray();
java.io.FileInputStream fis = null;
try {
  fis = new java.io.FileInputStream("keyStoreName");
  ks.load(fis, password);
} finally {
  if (fis != null) {
    fis.close();
  }

  KeyStore.ProtectionParameter protParam = 
    new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(password);

  KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry skEntry = new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(sk);
  ks.setEntry("secretKeyAlias", skEntry, protParam);
```

But i am getting following Exception.

> Exception in thread "main" java.security.KeyStoreException: Uninitialized keystore
>   at java.security.KeyStore.setEntry(Unknown Source)

How to fix this error? Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I suggest you read the documentation for the [`KeyStore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html) class, try something yourself and let us know if you get stuck.

Comment: Do try and use the jceks key store for at least moderate protection and choose a hard to crack password (like a sentence including made up words).

Comment: Don't write code like this. Code that depends on the success of code in a prior `try` block should be inside that `try` block. In your case, if the file isn't found, the keystores isn't initialised, so you should not execute the remaining code.

Answer (score 2):

According to the `KeyStore` [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html) ,

> Before a keystore can be accessed, it must be `loaded`.

> In order to create an empty keystore, or if the keystore cannot be initialized from a stream, pass null as the stream argument.

so you are loading the KeyStore but what if a `FileNotFoundException` occures at
`fis = new java.io.FileInputStream("keyStoreName");` , hence if file does not exist we load the KeyStore with `null` values ,like , `ks.load(null,null);` .