# java Aes encryption using key file

Tags: java, cryptography, aes, secret-key

How can we store the KEY in a key file for AES encryption using java so that the key file can be used for decryption purpose.

```
    private static void storeKey(SecretKey key){
        byte[] keyb = key.getEncoded();
        FileOutputStream keyfos;
        try {
            File file = new File(generateKeyFilesPath);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            keyfos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            keyfos.write(keyb);
            keyfos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
private static SecretKeySpec getKey(String generateKeyFilesPath){
        SecretKeySpec key = null;
        try {
            File keyFile = new File(path);
            FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(keyFile);
            byte[] bytesArray = new byte[(int) keyFile.length()];
            stream.read(bytesArray); 
            stream.close();
            key =  new SecretKeySpec(bytesArray, "AES");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return key;
    }
```

Unable to decrypt the cipher using the stored key(file),

Comment: Look into the Java Key Store

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406884/storing-aes-secret-key-using-keystore-in-java

Comment: Did you try Keystore? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html check load and store methods.

Comment: keystore approach is not portable, try to use OpenSSL instead

Comment: Can you please suggest how to use OpenSSL for AES encryption

Comment: How do you use this key to encrypt/decrypt your data? Show your code for these parts too. You may be missing something with padding and/or modes of operation.